# Expanding divs returned via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Consider the following Javascript jQuery code for dynamically expanding a div:

```
$('.expandingThumbnail').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '32px',
        width:  '32px'
    }, 500);
},function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '128px',
        width: '128px'
    }, 500);
});
```

It is operating on any theoretical div:

```
<div class="expandingThumbnail">Hi!</div>
```

So long as this div is returned as part of the page request, it expands as expected. However, if this div is returned as part of an AJAX request and inserted into another div via jQuery's `.html()` method, then the div does not expand as expected. Why is this, and how might I work around it?

Comment: can you provide the code written to expand the dynamically filled div ??

Comment: @AshishGupta doesn't matter really, it just means the content is not present at page load (i.e. it's not there when the js runs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the typical problem with dynamically generated content; direct event handlers only apply to elements which already exist when they are called. You need to bind your handler to a static parent element in order to handle the event triggered by new elements. See [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for details. Note that you can (*and should*) replace `document` below with a selector for the nearest, static parent element of `.expandingThumbnail` for improved performance.

```
$(document).on( 'mouseenter', '.expandingThumbnail', function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '32px',
        width:  '32px'
    }, 500);
}).on('mouseleave', '.expandingThumbnail', function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '128px',
        width: '128px'
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: @AD7six That was on its way :)

Comment: Thanks, nbrooks. `expandingThumbnail` actually doesn't have a single direct parent, these divs will appear under three different possible parent divs (which are also sent dynamically: `document -> staticDiv1 -> staticDiv2 -> dynamicTable -> dynamicTableTr -> dynamicTableTd -> expandingThumbnail` ). The code currently isn't working for me but I'm now googling the `on` method. Thanks for the impetus!

Comment: Nothing I seem to do with this method makes this work, even for non-AJAX content. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dotancohen/UwnCc/

Comment: @dotancohen your fiddle works fine if you choice jquery framework on left panel

Comment: Thank you! Also, in the application we use jQuery 1.6 but I see that the `on` method was added only in 1.7. Updating to 1.8.2 resolves the issue. Thanks!